# Why this equation is right aligned and others are not?

Tags: equations, amsmath, alignment

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,fit,shapes,calc}
\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, ticks=none}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{properties}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[properties]{label=Proprietà \arabic*.,itemindent=*}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hfil$}p{1.5cm}<{$\hfil}}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}

\date{}
\title{Notes}
\author{Myself}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\subsection{Sommatorie}
\begin{equation}
a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots+a_{n}= \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}
\end{equation}
\begin{properties}
\item Prodotto per una costante:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}(c \cdot a_{k}) = c \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} 
\end{equation}
\item Sommatoria con termine costante:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}c = c \cdot n
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=m}^{n}(c) = c\cdot (n-m+1)
\end{equation}
\item Sommatoria di sommatorie:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k} \pm \sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{k} \pm b_{k}) 
\end{equation}
\item Scomposizione di una sommatoria:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m}a_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+m} a_{k} 
\end{equation}
\item Traslazione di indici
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}  = \sum_{k=1+m}^{n+m} a_{k-m} 
\end{equation}
\item Riflessione di indici:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{n-k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_{n-k} 
\end{equation}
\item Doppia sommatoria:
\begin{equation}
a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+\dots+a_{2,1}+a_{2,2}+\dots+a_{n,m}= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i,j} =\sum_{j=1}^{m} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  a_{i,j}
\end{equation}
oppure:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i}b_{j}
\end{equation}
\item Scomposizione doppia sommatoria:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i}b_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( a_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{m} b_{j} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{m} b_{j} 
\end{equation}
\item Cambio d'ordine
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i}^{n} a_{i,j} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{j} a_{i,j}
\end{equation}
\item Quadrato di sommatoria
\begin{equation}
\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cdot a_{k} \right) ^{2} = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i}a_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2} + \sum_{i,j=1, i\neq j}^{n}a_{i}a_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2} + 2\sum_{i,j=1, i < j}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}
\end{equation}
\end{properties}

\end{document}
```

I tried with `\centering`, with `\begin{align}` and the `&` sign at the beginning of the equation line and with `\beign{gather}` instead of `\begin{equation}`, tried with `\begin{aligned}`, inside `\begin{equation}`. Any suggestion? The document is an article with 2.5 cm margins.

Comment: It's really impossible to say without seeing a complete, minimal code. Copy-pasting this equation in a minimal document shows no right alignment, so there must be something else going on, caused by code you are withholding.

Comment: Ok, I added some other code lines from my file. Thank you

Comment: First of, it **is** of course very important that you tell us that all of these are inside a list. Secondly, they are centered, but relative to the line width inside the list items. The boundaries of the list items are easier to see if you load the `kantlipsum` package and add `\kant[1]` to, say the first item.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Is it possible to modify only this particular list in order to have equations centered?

Comment: Centered in comparison to what? the outer edges? I think the ams classes does this, but it looks horrible. BTW you should probably take a look at the envs from amsmath, no-one writes several `equation`'s straight after each other

Comment: Centered in comparison to the page margins. What do you mean? What do you suggest is it better to do for having such number of equations in the same page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As daleif pointed out in his comment the equations in a list are centred with respect to the list's lines. Since lists have usually a left margin, this results in equations which look shifted to the right in comparison to the others.

You *could* use the features of `enumitem` in order to add a negative kern at the start of every math formula. However, in my opinion you should simply break the equation, which is too long for a single line. Anyway, this is what you seem to want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{properties}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[properties]{label=Proprietà \arabic*.,itemindent=*,before={\everydisplay{\kern-\leftmargin}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]
\[a=b\]
Here a standard list, showing the difference:
\begin{itemize}
\item blabla\[a=b\]
\item blabla\[a=b\]
\end{itemize}
And here the ``corrected'' version of your list:
\begin{properties}
\item blabla\[a=b\]
\item blabla\[a=b\]
\item Quadrato di sommatoria
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\biggl( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \biggr)^{\!\!2}
&= \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \biggr) \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \biggr)
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i}a_{j} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2} + \sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\neq j}}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}
= \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2} + 2\sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i < j}}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{properties}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know if it is related to the self defined list or not, but the "Proprietà 10. Quadrato di una sommatoria" to me looks bigger than other list items and also is a little bit more left aligned than other items. Same for you?

Comment: @Barbab bigger no, shifted left yes. That's likely a consequence of the list, I think `enumitem` assumes that the widest label contains only one figure. You should look into the `enumitem` documentation for the `widest` parameter but I'm not sure. I never really used `enumitem` and I don't know how it works in detail.

Comment: Fixed by replacing: `\setlist[properties]{label=Proprietà \arabic*.,itemindent=*,before={\everydisplay{\kern-\leftmargin}}, align=left, labelwidth=1ex}`

Answer (score 3):

If you want that the displays are centered with respect to the overall margin and not with respect to the line width in lists, you can do the same as the AMS classes do (although it's more common that people ask for the reverse).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,fit,shapes,calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\geometry{left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, ticks=none}

%\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hfil$}p{1.5cm}<{$\hfil}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}w{c}{1.5cm}<{$}}

\newlist{properties}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[properties]{label=Proprietà \arabic*.,itemindent=*}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dom}{dom}

\providecommand\fullwidthdisplay{%
  \setlength{\displayindent}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\displaywidth}{\columnwidth}%
}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\expandafter\fullwidthdisplay\the\everydisplay}


\date{}
\title{Notes}
\author{Myself}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\subsection{Sommatorie}
\begin{equation}
a_{1}+a_{2}+\dots+a_{n}= \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}
\end{equation}
\begin{properties}
\item Prodotto per una costante:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}(c \cdot a_{k}) = c \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} 
\end{equation}
\item Sommatoria con termine costante:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}c = c \cdot n
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=m}^{n}(c) = c\cdot (n-m+1)
\end{equation}
\item Sommatoria di sommatorie:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k} \pm \sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (a_{k} \pm b_{k}) 
\end{equation}
\item Scomposizione di una sommatoria:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k} + \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m}a_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+m} a_{k} 
\end{equation}
\item Traslazione di indici
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}  = \sum_{k=1+m}^{n+m} a_{k-m} 
\end{equation}
\item Riflessione di indici:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{n-k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_{n-k} 
\end{equation}
\item Doppia sommatoria:
\begin{equation}
a_{1,1}+a_{1,2}+\dots+a_{2,1}+a_{2,2}+\dots+a_{n,m}= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i,j} =\sum_{j=1}^{m} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  a_{i,j}
\end{equation}
oppure:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i}b_{j}
\end{equation}
\item Scomposizione doppia sommatoria:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i}b_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( a_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{m} b_{j} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \sum_{j=1}^{m} b_{j} 
\end{equation}
\item Cambio d'ordine
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i}^{n} a_{i,j} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{j} a_{i,j}
\end{equation}
\item Quadrato di sommatoria
\begin{equation}
\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cdot a_{k} \right) ^{2} = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \right) \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i}a_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2} + \sum_{i,j=1, i\neq j}^{n}a_{i}a_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2} + 2\sum_{i,j=1, i < j}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}
\end{equation}
\end{properties}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I reorganized your document preamble dividing packages in groups and doing set up after package loading. Note the different definition of the `C` column type.

Beware of using `\left` and `\right`, because they can give oversized fences (look at “Proprietà 8”). For “Proprietà 10” you might use

```
\item Quadrato di sommatoria
\begin{equation}
\biggl(\, \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cdot a_{k} \biggr) ^{\!2} =
\biggl(\, \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \biggr) \biggl(\, \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k} \biggr) =
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i}a_{j} =
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2} + \sum_{\substack{i,j=1 \\ i\neq j}}^{n} a_{i}a_{j} =
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2} + 2\sum_{\substack{i,j=1 \\ i < j}}^{n}a_{i}a_{j}
\end{equation}
```

Note `\,` after `\biggl(` to avoid a clash.

[image]